# Cannot find module svg module or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, react-native, metro-bundler

Please bear with me as I'm new to typescript, metro.config and react-native.

I'm receiving the following error after trying to use react-native-svg alongside react-native-svg-transformer. The SVG is showing so I think the metro.config.js is enabling the correct parsing of the .svg file.

UPDATE: I added an "exclude" prop in the tsconfig.json file, because I noticed a jest module in the node_modules folder..

```
[{
    "resource": "App.tsx",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2307",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot find module './new_dartboard.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.",
    "source": "ts",
}]
```

here are my dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.4",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  }
```

Lastly here is my ts.config file.

```
// prettier-ignore
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",     /* Recommended React Native TSConfig base */
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
    "baseUrl": "./",
    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", "dist"
  ],
  "allowJs": true,
  "checkJs": true
}
```

Comment: Have you run `npm run dev`, yet? This can initialize config files, which can change how your IDE reads the files.